# Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0, Gradle v7.6 is only installed and required

Tags: cordova, gradle, gradle-plugin, visual-studio-cordova

I have installed the latest version of cordova on windows 10.
I have installed the required version of gradle which is gradle 7.6

When run cordova build android i get the following error.

```
Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

See https://docs.gradle.org/7.6/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 2m 16s
17 actionable tasks: 17 executed
Command failed with exit code 1: C:\CordovaApps\Apps\MyApp\platforms\android\gradlew -b C:\Users\samp\Desktop\CordovaApps\MyApp\platforms\android\build.gradle cdvBuildDebug
```

I have tried upgrading and downgrading gradle versions without success.

Any information i have read beyond that state to modify the build.gradle file. But im not sure what to modify in it.

Any advice would be great